# Reverse proxy in IIS7

Tags: iis, proxy, redirect

We have an app that uses a bunch of ASP.NET SOAP services, hosted on IIS7. Now we're trying to move the services to a different server. Problem is that the client has a hard-coded URL, and does not support redirects. Since both servers are shared, establishing a DNS alias would be unadvisable.

And the one responsible for this amazing design has left the organization since, so we cannot even fire them.

Is there a piece of software out there that does completely server-side redirection? That is, it sits in a virtual folder, takes all requests, passes the headers and the POST data to another URL elsewhere and spits out whatever the said URL returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use URL Rewrite module in conjunction with [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting) to implement Reverse Proxy.

If you do not want to use those free modules by Microsoft, try [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/) -- it implements most of Apache modules on IIS 7 (then you can use Apache-style commands to achieve the same).